# Basic login controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5, asp.net-identity

I am implementing my first ASP.NET MVC web application and it is a questionnaire for university students. I have already implemented model, some controllers and views.

What I need now is login controller. I will have some roles: administrator, student, professor and teaching assistant. I have already implemented model classes for these profiles, but didn't add anything for logging in. What is the most appropriate way to implement secure logging in my case? What to use? Will I add some attributes to these classes like username and password or will have separated tables for users generated by some tool?

When I tried to use ASP.NET Identity it generated some tables in database and deleted tables for my existing model. Do I need to store tables for my model in separate detabase or what?

Comment: Use ASP.Net Identity.

Comment: Microsoft has already built frameworks to handle these scenarios.  It's best not to reinvent (the wheel) that someone else has already implemented, escpecially when security/authentication/authorization is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Identity Foundation is the way to go. It's built into ASP.NET MVC with it's own ApplicationDB Context that you can customize to fit with your application model.

Implementing this will provide you with corresponding classes in your DB called ApplicationUsers, AspNetRoles, AspNetUserLogins, AspNetUserRoles, and AspNetUsers. You can apply foreign keys to the ApplicationUsers table (from within code if you're using the Code First approach).

It's succint, secure, and easy to implement.

Comment: Will I have foreign keys for instances of both Student, Professor, Teaching Assistant in AspNetUsers?

Comment: I hope you've created a generic Person class from which your other people-types extend. If so, then you could reference the PersonId as a foreign key to the Id field in AspNetUsers. Only thing you  might want to be aware of is that the Id field is of type string and (nvarchar(128)) in the DB. It'll be a hashed id that you could assign to your person object when it is created.

Comment: So PersonId should also be of type string? When I create user will I also create person and put PersonId to be Id of that user in AspNetUsers?

Comment: Correct, it should be of type string. And yes, when the user is created assign the id of the ApplicationUser to the id in the Person class when creating the Person object. Are you using the Code First approach?

Comment: Yes, I use Code First approach. Do I firstly create ApplicationUser or Person object? Is the Id of user in AspNetUsers same as the username of user which will be of my choice?

Comment: I recommend you create a new ASP.NET MVC project (not an empty one) with scaffolding (if you don't already have these classes in your project) and look at the AccountController's Register method. A new user is created using an ApplicationUser object - the class of which resides in the IdentityModel class. In that class, you can specify additional fields if required. You can customize the Register method, such that you can create a Person object there and add it to the database.